# How to add "li" to "ul" tag with C#

Tags: html, sql, htmlgenericcontrol

i am trying to get some names from Sql database and append them as "li" in to pre-created "ul" with the code below. i am getting "System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal" instead my datas in Sql what could be the problem?

also with this code i cannot take first item in SQL. i mean totaly i have 9 item in Sql however i get only 8 "System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal".

the code:

HTML

```
<div class="modal-body" style="width: 1000px;">
    <ul class="list-group" runat="server" id="A3List">
    </ul>
</div>
```

C#

```
protected void loadEval_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("select name from A3_Coaching", con.connection());
    SqlDataReader dr = comd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        foreach (var r in dr)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            A3List.Controls.Add(li);
            li.InnerHtml = r.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regardless of your actual question: You should always make sure to dispose your SqlCommand and SqlDataReader. The safest ways is a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: @Mythran if you found the answer helpful then don't forget to upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the actual column name from the data reader not just do a .ToString which will print out the underlying type's name.  You don't need the extra foreach also, the while on the DataReader is your loop. Try the below.

```
protected void loadEval_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("select name from A3_Coaching", con.connection());
    SqlDataReader dr = comd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        A3List.Controls.Add(li);
        li.InnerHtml = dr["name"];        
    }
}
```